# Selecting a specific row based on value in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I followed this tutorial for referencing my Google Sheets in my web https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtq2xTWK7h4 .

```
    <script>
      let SHEET_ID = '(spreadsheet ID)'
      let SHEET_TITLE = "Sheet1"
      let SHEET_RANGE = 'A1:G1000'

      let FULL_URL = ('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SHEET_ID + '/gviz/tq?sheet=' + SHEET_TITLE + '&range=' + SHEET_RANGE);

      fetch(FULL_URL)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(rep => {
        let data = JSON.parse(rep.substr(47).slice(0,-2));

        let Ticket_Number = document.getElementById('Ticket_Number');
        let Ticket_Name = document.getElementById('Ticket_Name');
        let Ticket_Date = document.getElementById('Ticket_Date');
        let Ticket_Timeslot = document.getElementById('Ticket_Timeslot');
        
        console.log(data.table.rows[5])
      })      
    </script>
```

Through "console.log(data.table.rows[5])", changing the [5] to any number allows me to refer to different rows within my Google spreadsheet (eg: 0 = row 1, 1 = row 2, and so on).

Is there a way I could reference a specific row based on a value contained in that row?

For example, I want to select row 7 through something like, if row contains "2010202305000006", select that row.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxYmw.png).

I plan to then get values from this row.

I tried experimenting around with includes(),

```
console.log(data.table.rows.includes("2010202305000006")
```

but the console would only display "false". Or maybe is there maybe a better way to maybe link my spreadsheet?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following modification?

From your question and your provided image, I guessed that your situation is as follows.

- You have a publicly shared Google Spreadsheet.
- "Sheet1" in the Spreadsheet has columns "A" to "G".
- You want to search for a value of "2010202305000006" from column "B". And, when the value is found, you want to retrieve the rows.
- You want to achieve this using the fetch API of Javascript.

In this case, how about using the search query? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
<script>
let SHEET_ID = '(spreadsheet ID)'
let SHEET_TITLE = "Sheet1"
let SHEET_RANGE = 'A1:G1000'

let searchValue = '2010202305000006'; // This search value is from your question.

let FULL_URL = ('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SHEET_ID + '/gviz/tq?sheet=' + SHEET_TITLE + '&range=' + SHEET_RANGE + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(`SELECT * WHERE B='${searchValue}'`));

fetch(FULL_URL)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(rep => {
    let data = JSON.parse(rep.substr(47).slice(0, -2));

    let Ticket_Number = document.getElementById('Ticket_Number');
    let Ticket_Name = document.getElementById('Ticket_Name');
    let Ticket_Date = document.getElementById('Ticket_Date');
    let Ticket_Timeslot = document.getElementById('Ticket_Timeslot');

    if (data.table.rows.length > 0) {
      const res = data.table.rows.map(({ c }) => c.map(({ v }) => v));
      console.log(res);
    } else {
      console.log("Value was not found.");
    }
  });
</script>
```

- When this script is run, the row values are retrieved by searching with a query of `SELECT * WHERE B='${searchValue}'`. And, the values are parsed, and you can see it as a 2-dimensional array in the console.

#### Reference:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

### Added:

About your following new question,

> Just another question, how do I then refer the content of each columns just like in the picture?

> [image]

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
if (data.table.rows.length > 0) {
  const res = data.table.rows.map(({ c }) => c.map(({ v }) => v));
  console.log(res);
} else {
  console.log("Value was not found.");
}
```

#### To:

```js
if (data.table.rows.length > 0) {
  const res = data.table.rows.map(({ c }) => c.map(({ v }) => v));
  console.log(res);

  Ticket_Number.textContent = res[0][1];
  Ticket_Name.textContent = res[0][2];
  Ticket_Date.textContent = res[0][4];
  Ticket_Timeslot.textContent = res[0][5];
} else {
  console.log("Value was not found.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time answering my question.

I disagree that you said your english is not good because you understood my situation perfectly :) 

Your solution is perfect and now im able to refer the row (you can see in the console). Just another question, how do I then refer the content of each columns just like in the picture? 

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZh2w.png

I'm a complete beginner so apologize if I overcomplicate things. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer About your new question of `how do I then refer the content of each columns just like in the picture?`, I added a modification point of my proposed script. Please confirm it.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, Your modified script also works. Thank you so much once again :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.